# How should you refer to other people's result when writing in math?

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing, article-writing, convention, publishing

Here is what I was taught about coming up with my own results in math school:

> A lemma builds up to a theorem, which implies corollaries. A theorem
>   you are not proud of is a proposition.

However, I was never taught how I should refer, reference, cite or reprint other people's result.

- For example, suppose author $A$ has written a paper which contains
  theorem $A$ (for instance, De Moivre's Theorem). When referencing (and reprinting) his or her theorem $A$,
  should you refer to it as a theorem? But suppose you are using
  theorem $A$ to build your own theorem, then such a theorem could
  better be served as a lemma.

*Should this theorem be referred to as "Lemma (theorem $A$ from author $A$)", or "Theorem (theorem $A$ from author $A$)"?*

- Consider another scenario, an author $A$ has a famous so called "lemma
  $A$" (for instance, Borel Lemma). For your application, such a lemma could better serve the role
  of a theorem, for which you derive corollaries from. Should you cite
  his or her lemma as "lemma" or a "theorem"?

*Should this lemma be referred to as, "Theorem (lemma $A$ from author $A$)", or "Lemma (Lemma $A$ from author $A$)"?*

Similarly, how should you reference other people's propositions, corollaries, and or "remarks", "observations", "claims"? Is there a convention which is to be followed?

Comment: I don't think there is any definable convention. When in doubt, call it a result. Some results have standard names that are odd. Urysohnn's Lemma is a major tool in topology. A minor result of Konig  is called Konig's Theorem and a major one is  Konig's Lemma.  Results that are equations are often called Formulas: DeMoivre's Formula, the Hadamard Radius Formula,... I suppose it would be OK to call it whatever the originator called it.... It occurs to me that the nuances of the different meanings of theorem, lemma,etc., may differ in different languages.